# update a function defined in html file from a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I defined a function in my html file which returns the center of map:

```
<script>
rf = function (){
   return map.getCenter().wrap();
};
</script>
<script src='./f.js'></script>
```

Then I call this function from "f.js", simply by:

```
var center = (rf())
```

The problem is when I move the map the center is the same as before.

Thanks

PS: The function works perfectly in console.

Comment: did u try with `var center = (window.rf())`? cause wieved from the f.js file the `rf`function is in the global scope (window)

Comment: @toesslab.ch Yes, I tried, and it is not working too.

Comment: did you call `rf()` in a callback function?

Comment: Do you call `rf()` upon an event? can you do a fiddle or similar? Cause `var center = (rf())`does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

When you move the map you should run `center = (rf())` to set `center` again because `center` will not change with result of `map.getCenter().wrap()`